# Varchar to Int Conversion Error In Cursor Example

Tags: sql, cursor

First time I am trying cursor but getting the error for the varchar data type only. 
Error is **"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SGS' to data type int"**

In my table StationID is INT and Station is VARCHAR.

I have written this code to show I am able to print the int, but when I try with the varchar I am unable to print.

```
DECLARE @vStationID INT, @vStation VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR
FOR 
SELECT StationID, Station FROM TblStation WHERE StationID='2'
OPEN MyCursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor
INTO @vStationID,@vStation
PRINT @vStationID+' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@vStation)
CLOSE MyCursor
DEALLOCATE MyCursor
```

Please tell me what is the error in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @vStationID INT, @vStation VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR
FOR 
SELECT StationID, Station FROM TblStation WHERE StationID='2'
OPEN MyCursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor
INTO @vStationID,@vStation
PRINT convert(varchar,@vStationID)+' '+@vStation
CLOSE MyCursor
DEALLOCATE MyCursor
```

Comment: Thanks it worked ! But Can you tell me should i keep both Data type same to print? why did you convert stationID to Varchar ?

Comment: Yes it will take basing on priority basis, u can change convert(varchar,@vstation) to @vstation. PRINT convert(varchar,@vStationID)+' '+@vStation

Comment: For more clarity see the concatenation rules while concatineating two values.